# Help Understanding Gradients

Tags: continuity, partial-derivative

I understand that gradients are vectors with partial derivatives as components when working in 3D space, but does the the existence of a gradient at a point imply continuity at that point?

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly, but if you have a derivative at a point, the function should be continuous in that point.

Comment: Does this apply to the partial derivatives in a gradient?

Comment: @yoki, the existence of partial derivatives is weaker than differentiability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/561930/231643), it gives a counter-example of a function with partial derivatives at the origin that is not continuous.
This is because not every path to the origin yields the same limit.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's [Differentiable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) article has this neat 2-d example:

> $f(x,y) = \begin{cases}x & \text{if }y \ne x^2 \\ 0 & \text{if }y = x^2\end{cases}$

The gradient is uniquely defined at point $(0, 0)$, unaffected by the choice of axes along which you take the partial derivatives, but the discontinuity also exists to the limiting point $(0, 0)$. @TonyK comments that this function is continuous at $(0, 0)$. How about then:

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }y \ne x^2 \text{ or } x = 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }y = x^2 \text{ and } x \ne 0\end{cases}$

Comment: This function is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: That's better!$ $